# Java Scanner nextDouble command skipping values with switch case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm scanning an argument file with a switch case into a `Stack` and it's skipping over values with a `.nextDouble` command?

Here is my code fragment:

```
while (stackScanner.hasNextLine()) {        

    switch(stackScanner.next()) { 

    case"+": {
        operator= new operationNode("+");
        stack.push(operator);}

    case"-":{
        operator= new operationNode("-");
        stack.push(operator);}

    case"*":{
        operator= new operationNode("*");
        stack.push(operator);}

    case"/":{
        operator= new operationNode("/");
        stack.push(operator);}

    case"^":{
        operator= new operationNode("^");
        stack.push(operator);}

    while(stackScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        stack.push(new numberNode(stackScanner.nextDouble()));
    }
}
```

The problem is in this last line here, where the argument file contains the following: `^ 2 - 3 / 2 6 * 8 + 2.5 3`

Yet, the scanner only collects: `^ 2 - 3 / 6 * 8 + 3`.

So it's skipping over the first numbers that come in a pair here (2 and 2.5).

Thing is, when I add `stackScanner.next();` at the end of the while loop, the only numbers that it saves are those values 2 and 2.5?

Comment: Have you noticed that you have no break in your cases, and that your while loop is inside the switch statement?

Comment: @MauricePerry i had it as default: but it wasn't reading certain values. Also breaks don't seem to impact my result(?)

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the real code? When I copy and paste it I'm not seeing the results you say you're seeing. In particular, my stack looks like: `[^, 2.0, -, *, /, ^, 3.0, /, ^, 2.0, 6.0, *, /, ^, 8.0, +, -, *, /, ^, 2.5, 3.0]`, which is consistent with @MauricePerry's observation that you are missing `break` statements.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave oh I totally realize what I was doing wrong-- wasn't reading the stack correctly.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying your code and modifying slightly to use a `Stack<String>` rather than implementing your `operationNode` and `numberNode` classes, I find that the following works as (I think) you expect:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner stackScanner = new Scanner("^ 2 - 3 / 2 6 * 8 + 2.5 3");

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

    while (stackScanner.hasNextLine()) {

        switch (stackScanner.next()) {
            case "+": {
                stack.push("+");
                break;
            }

            case "-": {
                stack.push("-");
                break;
            }

            case "*": {
                stack.push("*");
                break;
            }

            case "/": {
                stack.push("/");
                break;
            }

            case "^": {
                stack.push("^");
                break;
            }
        }

        while (stackScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            stack.push(Double.toString(stackScanner.nextDouble()));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(stack);
}
```

That is, I've added the `break;` statements, which you seem to not need (perhaps some sort of JVM difference?) and moved the `while` loop outside of the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `switch` into `while` and move the handling of `double` into `default` block, e.g.:

```
while (stackScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextToken = stackScanner.next();
    switch(nextToken) { 

    case"+": {
        System.out.println("+");
        break;
        }

    case"-":{
        System.out.println("-");
        break;
    }

    case"*":{
        System.out.println("*");
        break;
    }

    case"/":{
        System.out.println("/");
        break;
    }

    case"^":{
        System.out.println("^");
        break;
    }

    default:
        if(isDouble(nextToken)){
            //Do something
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

You also need to write a method to check for `double`. It would look something like this:

```
private boolean isDouble(String number){
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(number);
        return true;
    }Catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I don't think this is actually correct. This will only process a single token per line. If the input is a single line - "^ 2 - 3 / 2 6 * 8 + 2.5 3", it will process the "^" and then stop.